# Ceiling fan fixture's lights flicker then the whole unit fails completely

Tags: electrical, repair, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I have two remote controlled ceiling fan fixtures in my living room. The individual units are the same, three speed fans with three lights on each. One day, one of them began flickering after I flipped the wall switch on then the lights on that fixture went out. Neither the fan nor the lights have worked since. A few days later the same thing happened to the other fixture in the room. I tried flipping the circuit breaker and nothing happens, the breaker was not tripped when either fixture failed. I tried removing and tightening the bulbs, but it didn't work. I removed the casing to one of the fixtures and nothing looks burnt out or obviously damaged. Any information about the problem would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds to me like loose connections having shaken themselves free. But if you have to ask, I sorta hesitate to suggest trying to chase it down yourself...

Comment: Using a non-contact tester, can you read power on the hot lead to the fan, or remote control, when the wall switch is on? (If you do not know how to do this safely, as @keshlam suggests, you probably should call in a pro.)

Comment: Either both fans were installed incorrectly or they are both defective. Providing the community with the model of the fan in question might also help solve the issue.